# How do I create a circular progress bar that looks like a timer?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create some app whose interface would look similar to the one in the link below. It is a circular shape with a greyish border + the white ‘thingy’ that fills up when the time has elapsed. It would be like a timer (Javascript). I’ve been pondering over how to go about this, tried some stuff but still no success as of yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Link: https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/45d32a70-45ff-4804-9ac3-f6d99d98e235/Joj-zpRkNbkBPb_zhEknJd2SyfxJ7SDc-bEFWliGG7AqQaaIP10cf3NkbpbeInLK5A=h900

Comment: you should read [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Just asking without any attempt to write even a single line of code not even considered for many

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but this guy makes something in that direction with circular shapes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQxt6TdzsAo - Good luck.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar I actually tried it but did not think the it would be useful since the HTML part was only one line of code (a div) as I'm yet to get to the JS part. I was only trying to get the UI done before embarking on the behind the scenes work.

Comment: @broodjetom Thanks for the link. Will look it up.

Comment: Once you may think as if it's 12:00 and then move it clockwise with `css` integrations. You should get the exact date & time via `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something similar

Markup

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="m-progress-loader">
        <div class="m-progress-loader--fill"></div>
        <div class="m-progress-loader--mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-progress-loader is-done">
        <div class="m-progress-loader--fill"></div>
        <div class="m-progress-loader--mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
    padding: 40px;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%,
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes mask {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50%,
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

$publishing-loader-color: #74da7a;
$scheduling-loader-color: #f0cc4e;
$loader-color: #e6e6e6;
$loader-color-darken: darken($loader-color, 20%);
$loader-mask-color: #f3f5f6;
$load-size: 6rem;
$load-border-size: 0.7rem;
$load-done-border-size: 1rem;
$spin-duration: 2s;
.m-progress-loader {
    margin: 30px; // for demo;
    font-size: $load-size;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: $loader-color;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: " ";
        width: 0.5em;
        height: 1em;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: $loader-color-darken;
    }
    &:before {
        transform-origin: 0.5em 0.5em;
        animation: spin $spin-duration linear infinite;
        border-radius: 999px 0 0 999px;
    }
    &:after {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 0 999px 999px 0;
        animation: fill $spin-duration steps(1, end) infinite;
    }
    &.is-done {
        &:before,
        &:after {
            opacity: 1;
            animation: none;
        }
        .m-progress-loader--mask {
            animation: none;
            background: $loader-mask-color;
            width: 0.5em;
            height: 0.25em;
            border-radius: 0;
            z-index: 4;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform-origin: center;
            transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(-45deg);
            &:before,
            &:after {
                content: " ";
                background: $loader-color-darken;
                border-radius: 1em;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            &:before {
                height: 100%;
                width: 0.09em;
            }
            &:after {
                height: 0.09em;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}

.m-progress-loader--fill {
    height: 0.9em;
    width: 0.9em;
    background: $loader-mask-color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.m-progress-loader--mask {
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: 999px 0 0 999px;
    animation: mask $spin-duration steps(1, end) infinite;
}

.mm-progress-loader--publishing {
    &:before,
    &:after {
        background: $publishing-loader-color;
    }
    &.is-done .m-progress-loader--mask {
        &:before,
        &:after {
            background: $publishing-loader-color;
        }
    }
}

.mm-progress-loader--scheduling {
    &:before,
    &:after {
        background: $scheduling-loader-color;
    }
    &.is-done .m-progress-loader--mask {
        &:before,
        &:after {
            background: $scheduling-loader-color;
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/robi_osahan/z2v7xorn/